# Odometer.js Does Not Work within Meteor?

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor

I'm trying to get reactive numbers in my Meteor template to animate using [odometer.js](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/). But it seems like I can't get past the first step - getting the  [odometer javascript code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HubSpot/odometer/v0.4.6/odometer.min.js) to run properly inside Meteor. When that code executes, it's supposed to find all DOM elements with the `.odometer` class and perform some DOM element manipulation based on the stylesheet theme you've selected in order to prepare the DOM for animated number manipulation. [Simple example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/adamschwartz/rx6BQ/)

For those not familiar with the library, if you inspect the jsFiddle after it runs you'll see what I mean by DOM manipulation. The script turns a simple `<div class="odometer"></div>` into a nested heirarchy:
[image]

The stylesheet loads properly in Meteor -- I can see the classes inside `application.css` if I poke around inside the `<head>` tag. But the script is not executing or not executing properly as the DOM never changes to the special class heirarchy that is needed for number manipulation.

- I've tried putting the script in a `client/script.js` file, no luck.
- I've tried putting the script in a `client/script.js` file, wrapping it a global function name, and calling that function from the template.rendered callback. No luck.
- I've tried embedding the odometer.js code directly within my template.rendered callback. No luck.

No JS error warnings are being printed to the console. Has anyone been able to get odometer to work within Meteor? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'the DOM never changes to the special class heirarchy that is needed for number manipulation' for people who haven't used this library before? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @danyll I added some additional detail, thanks

Comment: Try putting the script inside `/client/lib` directory. The library needs to be loaded before you can use it - I wrote more about load order [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/docs/client/full-api/concepts.html#L186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use any libraries, you need to put the script inside the `/client/lib` directory so it gets loaded first.

However, I wrote a package for `odometer` called [`d4nyll:odometeor`](https://github.com/d4nyll/odometeor), which has all the functionalities plus it allows you to use templating. A demo can be found at [odometeor.meteor.com](http://odometeor.meteor.com), it will change the number randomly every 4 seconds.

To use:

1. Run `meteor add d4nyll:odometeor`
2. Either include `{{> odometeor 888}}` inside your templates, or use `Odometeor.create()`
3. Change values directly using `$('.odometeor').html([--YOUR-NEW-NUMBER]);`

[Full documentation](https://github.com/d4nyll/odometeor)

Comment: I was able to pass in the helper name as an option, but not sure how to pass in a different theme name, like 'minimal'

Comment: To use a different theme, do the following: create a helper function which `return {theme: 'minimal', value: 800};`. Pass this helper into `{{> odometeor opts}}`. See http://odometeor.meteor.com/theme/ and https://github.com/d4nyll/odometeor/blob/master/examples/testing/client/js/theme.js